# accessing table data within a table in a table

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get specific contents of the second "datadisplaytable" is the Schedule type and Instructors name. The line below:

```
datadisplaytable = soup.find(class_='datadisplaytable').text
```

gets me the whole class which contains all other 'datadisplaytable's which I intend to loop through for the specific data that I need.
Using "Xpath" in selenium only gets me the contents of the selected path. and trying to use a for loop in selenium returns "WebElement not iterable'
Which brings me to the question,
How do I get the schedule type and Instructor.
catalog = https://prod-ssb-01.dccc.edu/PROD/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched
term and subject is any.

Answer (score 1):

Use `find_elements_by_xpath (‘<your xpath>)` not  `find_element_by_xpath`. See the difference one is with **s**.

Remember `find_elements` return a list of web elements which you can loop through where as `find_element` return a single web element.